# Responsive Background Image for Parallax Scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i am struggling my head to find a solution to my problem. I would like to implement simple parallax to my header image of my website. So i decided to use skrollr.js. However, i want the image to be responsive something i can not achieve with css background-image. When i use the `background-image: cover` property my image is cropped out in small sizes. Whenever i use `background-image: contain` the image scales down like how i want it but leaves a big white gap space below (the container does not resize accordingly) and i have position problems. Another hacky way i found was to use something like that:

```
<img src="/img/banner-bg.jpg" 
     class="img-responsive"  
     data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" 
     data-500="background-position:0px -250px;" />
```

like i saw in the skrollr.js documentation but unfortunately the animation wont work. All i want is a background-image but with the scaling options of img-responsive class.

Is there any way via javascript, jquery that i can use to scale the image accordingly? I am relatively new to jquery so i don't know how to use it properly yet.

The code i am using for my background-image:

```
image {
    background-image: url(/img/banner-bg.jpg);
    height: 680px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: Why not just create a element where height is relative to width, so on horizontal resize height will be always relative to the width? I mean when you set image via background-image property.

Answer (score 0):

After, not lying, 10 hours of searching I get it. I don't now why it works... But use this:
HTML

```
<div id="banner">Your Banner
</div>
```

CSS-code

```
 #banner {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        position: relative;
        clear: both;
        background: transparent url(../images/HeaderBild.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: 100%;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='path/to/image/1.jpg',sizingMethod='scale');
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='path/to/image/1.jpg',sizingMethod='scale')";

    }

    .wrap-center{
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        max-width: 73.231em;
    }

    .banner-centered {
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        max-width: 75.231em;
        height: inherit;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

    .banner-centered h2 {
        font-size: 5.385em;
        line-height: 1.5;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        color: #fafafa;
        font-weight: 100;
        display: block;
    }
```

And JS:

```
function scrollBanner() {
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
        $('#banner-text').css({
            'top' : (scrollPos/10)+'px',
            'opacity' : 1-(scrollPos/400)
        });
        $('#banner').css({
            'background-position' : 'center ' + (-scrollPos/2)+'px'
        });
    });
}
scrollBanner();
```